# AttributeError: type object 'platform' has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming a platformer, and trying to check if the player is in the air. If so, they fall down until they touch a platform, and then rise until they don't touch it anymore (so that they don't sink). To do this, I am checking whether the player's y position (plus height) is more than the platform's, referring to the whole 'platform' class, but this doesn't work:

Here is the initialisation code for the platform:

```
class platform(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
```

And here is where I refer to it:

```
def touchGround(self):
    while self.hitbox[1] + self.hitbox[3] > platform.y:
        self.speedY -= 1
        self.y += speedY

def fall(self):
    while self.hitbox[1] + self.hitbox[3] < platform.y:
        self.speedY += 1
        self.y += speedY
        touchGround()
```

However, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'platform' has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: You haven't instantiated an instance of your `platform` class. `y` is only defined in `__init__` and for that to run, you need to create an instance of `platform`. Also, class names should begin with capital letters, so `Platform`, and functions should be joined with underscore, so `touch_ground`

Comment: @roganjosh I forgot to mention that I have indeed instantiated an instance of `platform`, but in a list:  `platforms = [ ]` ... `p1 = platforms.append(platform(250, 350, 'medium'))`

Comment: Then this is totally unreproducible. You'll need to give more info that we might be able to run

Comment: @roganjosh Info as in...?

Comment: In terms of making a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `platform` in order for it to have the `y` attribute. Here's a simpler example of why this is the case:

```
class Something:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

if Something.y > 2:
    print('success')
```

No values have been defined at all, so it's unreasonable that any kind of comparison could be made. We could fix this with:

```
my_something = Something(1, 3)
if my_something.y > 2:
    print('success')
```

Or, you could fix it with defining a class variable:

```
class Something:
    x = 1
    y = 3

if Something.y > 2:
    print('success')
```

In your case, I assume you will have multiple platforms, so defining `x` and `y` at the class level probably doesn't make sense, since you'll want multiple instances with different attributes.

Separately, please see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions. These are important for clear understanding of code between people.